# Using a counting semaphore how do I create a recursive mutex

Tags: c, logic, bare-metal

I'm operating in a bare metal environment so any answers saying just use what you have don't apply as I don't have anything. I'm writing a system driver but I need recursive mutexes but I can't figure out how to implement them. I currently only have a counting semaphore that operates as a spinlock. Is it possible to create a recursive mutex from a semaphore or do I have to create another synchronization primitive and if so how? No code is required I just would like to know the steps please.

Comment: if bare-metal then how do you have a system to write a system driver for?  And why would you need recursive mutexes without a system?

Comment: It isn't quite bare-metal in the traditional sense. I'm writing my own system and I'm implementing the FAT32 filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some fairly weak nice properties on what happens under data races, it's light and easy, essentially:

```
/* data structure */
struct my_mutex {
    sem_t sem;
    volatile tid_t owner;
    unsigned count;
} m;

/* lock operation */
if (m->owner == self) { // formally a race
    m->cnt++;
} else {
    sem_wait(&m->sem);
    m->owner = self; // where self is tid of calling thread
}

/* unlock operation */
if (m->count > 0) {
    m->count--;
} else {
    m->owner = 0;
    sem_post(&m->sem);
}
```

Note that there is no ordering under which you could fail to see yourself as the owner when you are, nor see yourself as owner when you're not, assuming racing reads read some value from some possible ordering. But if you treat them as formally undefined, it's not valid.

If you can't do this, you normally need a normal mutex + condvar to emulate a recursive mutex, so first figure out how to make a condvar from a semaphore.

If your compiler has `_Atomic` and supports atomics of the right size for thread ids (the abstract `tid_t` type above; on bare metal this is a type you would define), you can make the `tid_t owner` member `_Atomic` and replace the test:

```
if (m->owner == self)
```

with:

```
if (atomic_load_explicit(&m->owner, memory_order_relaxed) == self)
```

and the `volatile` qualifier (largely unnecessary, but there as a signal to the compiler that it should not split or combine loads, which helps with the "weak nice properties" I was aiming for in the absence of atomics) can be removed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's well defined if `m->owner` is of an `_Atomic` type, even for `memory_order_relaxed` accesses.

Comment: Yes, if you have a C11 compiler supporting atomic it's well-defined.

Comment: Is the _Atomic type safe for bare metal or do I need to implement it using test and set in asm?

Comment: In theory atomic types for which the machine doesn't have a suitable-sized instruction will be implemented with locks, which would probably be okay anyway, but this isn't really something you need to worry about for reasonable types you could use for thread identifiers. If you could implement it in asm, a compiler implementing atomics properly should have it as a lock-free atomic.

Comment: Note that, with relaxed-order as EOF recommended, you're normally not even relying on any special atomic/barrier instructions at the machine level. It's closer to just being `volatile` - putting constraints on what transformations the compiler can perform - which would be a suitable hack for a relaxed-order atomic in my book if you're stuck with a pre-C11 compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your help I'm still confused slightly by your answer I know I said code wouldn't be nessecary but in this case it may be. Would you please help me and show me how this could be implemented with a compiler supporting C11? I am using the linaro gcc cross compiler for an AARCH64 platform if that changes anything.

Comment: @R.. Thank you that makes much more sense. That is actually easier to implement than I imagined. Thanks.